# ANTLR Match class name

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, lexical-analysis

In my grammar I have the rule for an assignment. It is the form 
`assignment: VAR_TYPE ID '=' expr;`

In `VAR_TYPE` I have some hardcoded values like Integer, String etc.

What I want to know is how can I match any class name that is declared in the file ?

Suppose someone declared `class Foo` and `Class Bar`. How can I mark this as valid input 
without utilising `ID`. Because if I ad `|ID` to the `VAR_TYPE` rule, `ID` will never be
matched and I don't want that.

Comment: Why not use `ID` instead of `VAR_TYPE` to begin with? Then, you can maintain an expandable container(this is language-specific; Use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) with C++, [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) with Python, [`System.Collecions.Generic.List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) with C#) of declared types and use it to keep track, throwing an error if an unknown type is used.

Comment: Ok. So your suggestion is to just drop VAR_TYPE ?

Comment: Pretty much. That's what I usually do to avoid over-complicating things. What language are you using??

Comment: Ok...theoretically, you would be able to modify the rule context at runtime. However, I've never used Java, so I can't help you there. And, just in case, here's Java's list implementation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't hard code your type names unless they are actually keywords in your language. Then you create a parser rule to match any type:

```
varType : ID;
assignment : varType ID '=' expr;
```

`Integer` and `String` would then be treated as regular `ID` tokens.

Use a listener after the parse is complete to validate that the `ID` appearing in each `varType` actually refers to a type.